# Connection refused displayed by by X2Go Client. Any ideas?

Tags: 22.04, x2go, x2goclient

I'm getting 'Connection refused' on my my Ubuntu 22.04 system which I'm using as a X2Go Client to a X2Go on a Debian PC. The Debian PC has port 22 open. Is there anything that one has to do on the Ubuntu X2Go Client?
PS the Server & Client PCs are on the same LAN. The Server has a static NAT address.

Comment: Basic troubleshooting: can you use X2Go client on the server to reach itself? Can you ping the server from the client? Can you `ssh -v` to the server? (As it's listening on port 22, you should get a response.)

Comment: https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/download:start

Answer (score 0):

X2Go is not compatible with Gnome nor with Raspbian desktop

Comment: The OP does no mention Raspbian.

Comment: I'm assuming that John Rose who asked the main question knows what desktop that he is using.